# iPhone Contact Picker behaviour (like in Mail.app)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

can you give me a hint how to customize such a contact picker from e.g. Mail or Facebook App with the (+) Adding Contacts (or other data) to a UITextField for recipients .. each of the entries can be deleted then with the (x) ..

can you give me a hint where to start and what i should customize? thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you talking about something like this:

[image: TTPickerTextField from Three20]

If so, you'll want to check out the [TTPicketTextField UI component](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/blob/master/src/Three20/TTPickerTextField.h) from the Three20 framework. It does exactly what you're after.

Comment: Thanks a gazilion! I've stumbled across Three20 before, but never realized it was so comprehensive.